# Can I use the same machine as a client and server for SSH?

Tags: sftp

For development tests, I need to setup an SFTP server.  So I want to know if it's possible to use the same machine as the client and the server.  I tried and I keep getting this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
Connection closed
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: i'm on windows machine, i already copied the public key into authorized_keys but still no result

Comment: Can your Windows ssh client do the equivalent of `ssh -v` in Unix clients, showing verbose messages about what it's doing?  My first guess is that it's a permissions problem for your key files, that they're either too secure for the ssh server to see, or too loose that the server thinks other users could tamper with them.

Answer (score 0):

[thecoshman] I'm under Windows XP, I'm using OpenSSH and to perform test I just use the command prompt.

[coneslayer] the command: `ssh -v` returns

> `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin>ssh -v agharroud@localhost` OpenSSH_3.8.1p1,OpenSSL 0.9.7d 17 Mar 2004`
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>   debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
>   debug1: Connection established. 
>   debug1: identity file /home/agharroud/.ssh/identity type -1 
>   debug1: identity file /home/agharroud/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
>   debug1: identity file /home/agharroud/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_3.8.1p1 pat OpenSSH*
>   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex:server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
>   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>   debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/agharroud/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT 
>   received
>
> ```
>                         ****USAGE WARNING****
> ```
>
> This is a private computer system.
>   This computer system, including all
>   related equipment, networks, and
>   network devices (specifically
>   including Internet access) are
>   provided only for authorized use. This
>   computer system may be monitored for
>   all lawful purposes, including to
>   ensure that its use is authorized, for
>   management of the system, to
>   facilitate protection against
>   unauthorized access, and to verify
>   security procedures, survivability,
>   and operational security. Monitoring
>   includes active attacks by authorized
>   entities to test or verify the
>   security of this system. During
>   monitoring, information may be
>   examined, recorded, copied and used
>   for authorized purposes. All
>   information, including personal
>   information, placed or sent over this
>   system may be monitored.
>
> Use of this computer system,
>   authorized or unauthorized,
>   constitutes consent to monitoring of
>   this system. Unauthorized use may
>   subject you to criminal prosecution.
>   Evidence of unauthorized use collected
>   during monitoring may be used for
>   administrative, criminal, or other
>   adverse action. Use of this system
>   constitutes consent to monitoring for
>   these purposes.
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Trying private key:/home/agharroud/.ssh/identity
>   debug1: Offering public key:/home/agharroud/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1:Authentications that can continue:publickey
>   debug1: Trying private key:/home/agharroud/.ssh/id_dsa
>   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: You still need to supply your normal arguments with `ssh -v`, for example `ssh -v username@hostname`.  (Also, the etiquette here would be to edit your question with the additional information, instead of posting it as an answer.)

Comment: any ideas about what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your question is specific about client=server or if you cannot deploy an sftp server at all.

You should check:

- Can you ssh to this machine with your username from another machine in first place?
- Have you installed and launched an ssh server yet?
- Is your username authorized to login in the ssh server configurations?
- Do you have firewalls enabled? Try disabling just for a test.

In linux I do it all the time, even when I just want to run a graphical application logged as another user but inside my desktop session:

```
ssh [-X] [-A] [etc] username@localhost
```

(Replace "username" by the name you will use to connect to the machine. Do not replace localhost, it's really meant to be called "localhost".)

I guess if you cannot even do ssh username@localhost you won't manage to perfom self sftp.